# Should __init__.py also contain python module imports?

Tags: python, python-import

When writing your own package in Python, should `__init__.py` contain imports like `os`, `sys`? Or should these just be imported within the file that is using them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the modules in the module that uses them.

Placing `import os` in `__init__.py` would put `os` in the package's global namespace, but it would not affect the namespace of the module that uses `os`. Global namespaces are not shared across modules or packages, so you would get `NameError`s if you did not import them in the module that uses `os`.

Comment: Putting `import os` however in `__init__.py` will affect any module that does `from my_awesome_package import *` because now they'll have the `os` module in their namespace affecting possible functions or global variables unexpectedly. While using `*` is frowned upon, enough people still use it and package authors should be considerate even of them

Comment: @sigmavirus24: Many modules and packages are designed specifically to support the `from xxx import *` coding-style and do so by defining a module- or package-level variable named `__all__` which contains a sequence of strings of the names of things defined by it (excluding anything not mentioned). For packages that is often created in the `__init_.py` file.

Comment: @martineau I'm well aware of that. OP was asking about putting that in there without mentioning that or anything else so I addressed the concerns with doing that and nothing else.